# Pass custom object in routerLink

Tags: angular6

I want to pass 2 parameters to `[routerLink]` a `string` and an `object`

```
<a [routerLink]="[questionDetailRouterLink, {'question-id':question['question-id'],'question-list':this.questions}]">Show more</a>
```

where
`questionDetailRouterLink` is `url`/`string`, `question['question-id']` maps to a `string` and `this.questions` is a `object` of class. So `this.questions` gets passed as its `toString()` equivalent i.e. `[Object object]`

On the receiving component side, I am trying to extract the values like this

```
this.question_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('question-id'); // question-details;question-id=:id'
this.questions = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('question-list'); //this gives [Object object]
```

I thought I could pass `JSON.stringify` version of the object (and do `JSON.parse` in receiving end) but I can't do this in the template `[routerLink]="[questionDetailRouterLink, {'question-id':question['question-id'],'question-list':JSON.parse(this.questions)}]"` - compilation error

How can I pass the object to another object (there are independent and are not parent/child) so I can't use `input` parameter as well

Answer (score 0):

I read of two options to solve my problem. The first one is using a `provider`. `Component A` updates the values in `provider P` before routing to `component B`. `Provider P` has a variable to hold the object to be passed which `A` updates and then `B` reads. other option is to create a parent/child relationship between A & B and use dynamic element creation to show B when needed (`ngContainer`, `ngTemplate`, `createEmbeddedView` etc.)